# Xamarin Update data inside CollectionView doesn't work

Tags: xamarin, collectionview

I've a CollectionView inside my Page and a label Name binding with class

```
<CollectionView Grid.Column="0"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    SelectionMode="Single"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding MarketplacePackages}">

            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
```

then i've a class Marketplace

```
public class MarketplacePackage
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and inside my ViewModel i've that

a listView

```
List<MarketplacePackage> marketplacePackages;
    public List<MarketplacePackage> MarketplacePackages
    {
        get { return marketplacePackages; }
        set { SetProperty(ref marketplacePackages, value); }
    }
```

a constructor where i initialize the list

```
public MarketplaceViewModel()
    {
        Catalogue = new Command(onCatalogueClicked);
        MyDevice = new Command(onMyDeviceClicked);
        MyOrders = new Command(onMyOrderdsClicked);

        MarketplacePackages = new List<MarketplacePackage>() {
            new MarketplacePackage()
            {
                Name = catalogueList[0],
            },
            new MarketplacePackage()
            {
                Name = catalogueList[1]
            },
            new MarketplacePackage()
            {
                Name = catalogueList[2]
            },
            new MarketplacePackage()
            {
                Name = catalogueList[3]
            }
        };

        //this works!
        //MarketplacePackages[0].Name = "String";
    }
```

and when i call onClickMethod i try to change the data inside my listView

```
private async void onCatalogueClicked()
    {
        MarketplacePackages[0].Name = "String";
    }
```

Comment: MarketplacePackage needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged - this is the mechanism that notifies the UI when a property has been updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `MarketplacePackage` class has to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface (or to inherit from `ObservableObject` if you're using XamarinCommunityToolkit or MvvmHelpers) and notify when the `Name` property is changed.

e.g.:

```
public class MarketplacePackage : ObservableObject
{
    string name;
    public string Name { get => name; set => SetProperty(ref name, value); }
}
```

It works when you set/change the `Name` property in the constructor of the ViewModel because the View reads the initial values after the constructor is finished.

Comment: I use BaseViewModel for my MarketplaceViewModel class which already extend INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: Yeah, but in your code the `Name` property doesn't notify when the value is changed.

Comment: You need to make sure that both `MarketplaceViewModel` and `MarketplacePackage` implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: i try but no change
`public class MarketplacePackage : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }`

Comment: Please take a look at this example (how the properties are raising the event): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/how-to-implement-the-inotifypropertychanged-interface?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: the `set` for `Name` must raise a `PropertyChanged` event.  You are doing this correctly elsewhere in your code.